# Regex code tested but not matching when used with sed

Tags: regex, sed, pipe

Why does the following

```
$ echo "test\|String" | sed 's/(?!\||\\)./&./g'
test\|String
```

Not produce:

```
t.e.s.t.\|S.t.r.i.n.g.
```

I have [tested the regex code](https://regex101.com/r/mL7dA6/1) and it picks the string up correctly in my tests

I want it to do the following:

```
$ echo "test\|String" | sed 's/(?!\||\\)./&./g'
t.e.s.t.\|S.t.r.i.n.g.
```

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do here?

Comment: trying to replace every matched character (call a positive match, `&`) with `&\.` for every character piped to `sed` i.e stick dots after all characters that are **not** `\ `, or `|`

Comment: Because that's a PCRE regex and sed doesn't do those.

Comment: In this case a character class (or negated character class)  is the obvious option. However if it were the combination of `\|` that needed to be treated as one, the following method can be employed: `sed 's/\\|/\n/g;s/[^\n]/&./g;s/\n/\\|/g' file` where the `\n` is used to replace the combination and following the operation restored to the original combination.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a regex" so all of these regex testing tools are of extremely limited use. A regex is only valid and only functions in a specific way in the context of whatever version of whatever tool you want to use since all tools that support regexps support different standards and/or private extensions and/or have additional caveats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have written what you describe like this:

```
echo "test\|String" | sed 's/[^\\|]/&./g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following produces the effect you want:

```
echo "test\|String" | perl -npe 's/(?!\||\\)./$&./g'
t.e.s.t.\|S.t.r.i.n.g.
```

Not all regular expression engines are the same.  You are using something close to PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), but the one used in `sed` is older, more limited, and has some quirks, like using `\(` and `\)` to match groups, rather than `(` and `)`.  It doesn't know about negative lookahead assertions.  Perl's `-n` and `-p` flags give it `sed`-like behavior.  Note finally that Perl uses `$&` to indicate "entire matched expression", not `&` alone.

The regular expression engines used by the shell, by `grep`, by `sed`, by Emacs, by POSIX, and by PCRE are all different; unless your regex is quite simple, you will need to target the specific engine.